# Moment Generating Function of R.V.'s Y/X?

Tags: probability, laplace-transform, moment-generating-functions

I want to calculate the MGF of 
$$
\left(\frac Y X \right)^\alpha,
$$
where R.V.'s $Y \in Exp(1)$, $X$ has the Laplace transform $L_X(s)=e^{-s^\alpha}$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

I'm thinking that maybe I could compute the MGF as
$$
\psi_{\left(\frac Y X\right)^\alpha}=\psi_{(Y^\alpha X^{-\alpha})}=E\left[e^{t(Y^\alpha X^{-\alpha})}\right]=
$$
$$
=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} e^{t \cdot y^\alpha \cdot x^{-\alpha}} f_X(x^{-\alpha}) f_Y(y^\alpha) dxdy
$$
However, this is where I get unsure of how to continue. Am I on the right path and how should I compute the PDF for Laplacian?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: @d.k.o. Yes! Sorry forgot to mention that